# How to middle align the content of the div with height 100vh?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
.components{
    background-color: #1DA1F2;
    text-align: left;
     height: 100vh;
     padding: 20px;
 }
```

I've used height:100vh on the outer div which surrounds the content but i cannot get the div content to align in the middle of the screen.  How can that be done ? The outer most div is .components and  the inner div is .row

Comment: Using `calc()`?

Comment: why don't you just continue with margin and by using media query

Comment: Make the outter div flex and align items center, and inner div width 100%

Comment: use `flex` and add the snippet of your code help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a simple example below ( Hope i understood what you wanted )

Just add `display:flex;align-items:center` on the `.components` . I used bootstrap but only for the cols to stay side by side . It doesn't matter how you arranged your layout , bootstrap or not, `display:flex` will work

```css
.components {
  background-color: #1DA1F2;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.row {
  width:100%;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  background:red;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="components">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      col
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```